# How to delete nan/null values in lists in a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with NaN values and I tranfsform all the rows in that dataframe in a list which then is added to another list.

```
Index   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ... 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
orderid                                                                                 
20000765    624380  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
20000766    624380  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
20000768    1305984 1305985 1305983 1306021 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

```
records = []
for i in range(0, 60550):
    records.append([str(dfpivot.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 10)])
```

However, a lot of rows contain NaN values which I want to delete from the list, before I put it in the list of lists. Where do I need to insert that code and how do I do this?

I thought that this code would do the trick, but I guess it looks only to the direct values in the 'list of lists':

```
records = [x for x in records if str(x) != 'nan']
```

I'm new to Python, so I'm still figuring out the basics.

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole row that contains a NaN or do you just want to retrieve a list from every row, where every list does not contain any nans?

Comment: The second. I want a list of every row, except the NaN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to keep rows with nans you can do it like this:

```
In [5457]: df.T.dropna(how='all').T                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5457]: 
         Index           1           2           3           4
0 20000765.000  624380.000         nan         nan         nan
1 20000766.000  624380.000         nan         nan         nan
2 20000768.000 1305984.000 1305985.000 1305983.000 1306021.000
```

if you don't want any columns with nans you can drop them like this:

```
In [5458]: df.T.dropna().T                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[5458]: 
         Index           1
0 20000765.000  624380.000
1 20000766.000  624380.000
2 20000768.000 1305984.000
```

To create the array:

```
In [5464]: df.T.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()).tolist()                                                                                                                                  
Out[5464]: 
[[20000765.0, 624380.0],
 [20000766.0, 624380.0],
 [20000768.0, 1305984.0, 1305985.0, 1305983.0, 1306021.0]]
```

or

```
df.T[1:].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()).tolist()                                                                                                                              

Out[5471]: [[624380.0], [624380.0], [1305984.0, 1305985.0, 1305983.0, 1306021.0]]
```

depending on how you want the array

Comment: Yes, thank you! The last one did the trick. However I had to use `df.T[0:].apply...`

Answer (score 3):

One way is to take advantage of the fact that [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) removes `NaNs` to generate the nested list:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).values.tolist()
# [[624380.0], [624380.0], [1305984.0, 1305985.0, 1305983.0, 1306021.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be with a nested list comprehension:

```
[[j for j in i if not pd.isna(j)] for i in dfpivot.values]
```

EDIT
it looks like you want strings - in which case,

```
[[str(j) for j in i if not pd.isna(j)] for i in dfpivot.values]
```